# How to access binding of ListView item from code-behind?

Tags: data-binding, maui

I have this ListView:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="ListViewTest" ItemsSource="{Binding TestObserv}"  MinimumWidthRequest="300">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <VerticalStackLayout Margin="10,10,10,10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="LightGray"></Label>
                    <Slider ClassId="{Binding name}" Value="{Binding value}" x:Name="TestSlider" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" HorizontalOptions="Start"  WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="MidnightBlue" ThumbColor="DarkViolet" MaximumTrackColor="MediumBlue" DragCompleted="TestSlider_DragComplated" ></Slider>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestSlider}, Path=Value, StringFormat='[{0:0.00000}]'}"></Label>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The slider controls some values and I change these values in the code-behind. I want to move the slider when a value changes.

Comment: According to the developer's answer in this [Access controls inside DataTemplate #3675](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3675), the elements in the `DataTemplate` are not accessible through code. Could you please update the requirement or scenario why you want to access the slider to the question?

Comment: The slider is checking some values ​​and I am changing these values ​​in the background trying to make my slider move to when ​​I changed the values.

Comment: You either use this:  x:Name="ListViewTest", and write all your code that way. Or you use this: ItemsSource="{Binding TestObserv}", and stick to binding. Everything in between is design choice bound to fail at some point. Also this slider 0-1 looks suspiciously like a switch to me. Anyway you are looking for < Slider ... Value=... />. The other 10 properties you have are mostly useless.

Comment: x:Name="ListViewTest" it's just for try some thing. I use only "ObservableCollection" with INotifyPropertyChanged class for listview design. That slider has 6 digit like "0.12345". except that one you are right I need only slider value in code line.

Comment: `TestListView.ItemsSource.Cast<TestObservableClass>().Where(x => x.name == "SliderName").FirstOrDefault().value = 0.0;` I think this line is working but not seems healty.

Comment: One approach: Learn how to make a custom control. Put the XAML inside `<ViewCell>` into its own xaml file. Then in the corresponding c# "code-behind" file, you can manipulate TestSlider  more easily.

Comment: You could add a Name or Id property in model class. And when the value changes, you could find the corresponding slider through the name of each item in TestObserv in code-behind or viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the value of the slider from the backend code, it is recommended that you use data two-way binding to do so from the `ViewModel`.

You could refer to the following example:

Step 1. Add a property in the Model class that binds to a slider.

```cs
public class Item:INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public string name { get; set; }

    private double _value;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") =>
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    public double value 
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set 
        { 
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }
}
```

Step 2. Add a Command in the ViewModel that manipulates `value`.

```cs
public ICommand ChangeSliderValueCommand => new Command<Item>(x => ChangeSliderValue(x)); 
private void ChangeSliderValue(Item item)
{
    item.value = 0.5;
}
```

Step 3. Use two-way binding in Xaml so that the ViewModel can modify the value of the Slider.

```xml
<ViewCell Height="400"> 
    <VerticalStackLayout Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="LightGray"></Label>
        <Slider ClassId="{Binding name}" x:Name="TestSlider" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" HorizontalOptions="Start"  WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="MidnightBlue" ThumbColor="DarkViolet" MaximumTrackColor="MediumBlue" Value="{Binding value,Mode=TwoWay}"></Slider>
        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestSlider}, Path=Value, StringFormat='[{0:0.00000}]'}"></Label>
        <Button Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TestViewModel}}, Path=ChangeSliderValueCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: Step 1 and step 3 is same as my code but  I can't understand how to select right slider in step 2. That could working just one slider or change all slider value. I use `TestListView.ItemsSource.Cast<TestObservableClass>().Where(x => x.name == "SliderName").FirstOrDefault().value = 0.0;`  this line for now it's working.